# Is finite group isomorphic with the direct prouct of the Sylow $p$ subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, direct-product

My question is the like the title

**'($\forall$ finite group, G) $\simeq$ ($\Pi$ the Sylow $p$ subgroups of the G)'**

I want to know this statement holds or not.(I'm not sure my proof is correct)

**My proof)** I'm not sure my trial is correct or not.

When the $\vert G\vert = p^n$, it is trivial that G is isomorphic with sylow p subgroup itself.

Let $\vert G \vert$ = $p_{1}^n p_{2}^m k$ for prime $p_1,p_2$ and $k\neq 1$ with $(p_1, k) = (p_2,k) =1$

Then, $\exists P_1$ and $P_2$  $s.t.$  $\vert P_1 \vert = p_1^n$  and $\vert P_2 \vert = p_2^m$ respectively.

(By sylow First thm,  $P_1$ and $P_2$ are sylow subgroups.)

Also $P_1 \cap P_2 = \{ e \}$ ($e$ means identity of the $G$)

And clearly, $P_1, P_2 \leq G$ which means subset(subgroups)

Hence, $\vert P_1P_2 \vert$  = ${\vert P_1 \vert \vert P_2 \vert} \over \vert P_1 \cap  P_2 \vert$ = $\vert P_1 \vert \vert P_2 \vert$

Therefore $k$ can be prime decomposed by the other primes, $p_i(\neq p_1, p_2)$

Same process Like the above, We can conclude

$\vert G \vert$ = $\Pi _1 ^n \vert P_i \vert  \Rightarrow  G  \simeq \Pi _1 ^n \ P_i$ (Since each $P_i$ are subsets of the G )

Comment: I see that you have tried hard to prove this result, but I think, before asking a question like this, you ought to also devote some effort to looking for counterexamples - that could save you a lot of time.  In your search you might start by looking at the smallest nonabelian group, which has order 6, and bingo! that is already a counterxample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect. The correct statement is:

*A finite group is isomorphic to the direct product of it's Sylow subgroups if and only if all of the group's Sylow subgroups are normal.*

See for instance Theorem 3.3 of [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowapp.pdf) blurb of Keith Conrad.

Comment: ...And this property is equivalent to being nilpotent.

Answer (score 7):

Others already explained that you don't get a direct product of groups for that needs the elements from distinct subgroups to commute (or both to be normal). You won't get even a semi-direct product for that would require one factor to be normal.

There is another fundamental problem in your approach. You won't even get a set of the prescribed size.

A building block in your argument seems to be the formula that if $H\le G, K\le G$, then we can form the set
$$
HK=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\},
$$
and it is an easy exercise to show that the size of this set is 
$$
|HK|=\frac{|H|\cdot|K|}{|H\cap K|}.\qquad(*)
$$
But then you run into the following problem:

> Formula $(*)$ is guaranteed to hold only if $H$ and $K$ are *both* subgroups.

You are still ok, when you form the product of two Sylow subgroups $P_1P_2$ (belonging to distinct primes $p_1\neq p_2$. But, $P_1P_2$ is not necessarily a subgroup, so when you add a third prime things may break down, and you don't necessarily have $|P_1P_2P_3|=|P_1|\cdot|P_2|\cdot|P_3|$.

As an example of this consider the group $A_5$ of order $60$. Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_1&=\langle (12)(34), (13)(24)\rangle,\ \text{a Sylow $2$-subgroup,}\\
P_2&=\langle (135)\rangle,\ \text{a Sylow $3$-subgroup,}\\
P_3&=\langle (14352)\rangle,\ \text{a Sylow $5$-subgroup.}
\end{aligned}
$$
When forming the products the following happens:
$$
((12)(34))(135)=(14352).
$$
Meaning that some elements of $P_3$ already belong the product $P_1P_2$. It follows that there is more than one way of writing $1_G$ in the form $1_G=x_1x_2x_3$ with $x_i\in P_i, i=1,2,3$. Consequently the set $P_1P_2P_3$ has less than the expected $4\cdot3\cdot5$ elements, and you have failed to get all $60$.

- In my example it is possible to "fix" the approach by using $P_2'=\langle (123)\rangle$ instead of $P_2$. For then both $P_1$ and $P_2'$ would be subgroups of a copy of $A_4$, and the product $P_1P_2'$ would necessarily be all of $A_4$. In other words, a subgroup. Implying that $(P_1P_2')P_3$ would be all of $A_5$ (but still neither a direct or even a semi-direct product).
- But, it is impossible to similarly "fix" all the cases. For example, the order in which the prime factors are processed will matter. If you want to make a subgroup of order $20$ as a product of a Sylow $2$-subgroup and a Sylow $5$-subgroup you run into the obstacle that *$A_5$ has no subgroups of order $20$.* Proof left as an exercise (consider the left action of $A_5$ on the cosets of such a subgroup to get a homomorphism from $A_5$ to $S_3$ and use the fact that $A_5$ is simple).
- In general the set $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if the sets $HK$ and $KH$ are the same set. This holds if at least one of $H$, $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. In general we don't have any normal Sylow subgroups, so your rocket may not even lift off let alone proceed to the second stage.

Comment: +1, nice observation regarding the possible failure of the counting formula when there are three factors.

Comment: Thank you for point out what I've missed. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is false for $S_3$ for example. Your proof shows that the group is the internal product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups, which is true but much weaker than showing it is the direct product.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the symmetric group $S_3$

If this group was a direct product of two of its Sylow subgroups $P_2$ and $P_3$, we would have

$$S_3 \cong P_2 \times P_3 \cong C_2\times C_3\cong C_6$$

and then $S_3$ is an abelian group, contradiction.

Groups for which this property holds are called **nilpotent groups.** The following statements are equivalent for a finite group $G$:

(1) $G$ is nilpotent

(2) Every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal.

(3) Every maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal.

(4) Every proper subset of $G$ is properly contained in its normalizer.

(5) $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

In particular, $S_3$ is not nilpotent. It is solvable though.